# A special form of Bezout lemma

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Let $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ be natural numbers and $d$ the gcd of all of them. Using Bezout lemma in number theory we can find integers $k_1, k_2,..., k_n$ such that $a_1k_1 + a_2k_2 + ... + a_nk_n = d$.

> Are there always integers $k_1,k_2,..., k_n$ such that $a_1k_1 + a_2k_2 + ... + a_nk_n = d$ and $k_2\mid k_3\mid k_4\mid \dots\mid k_n$ ?

I am trying to solve a linear algebra problem and in the middle of my solution I faced this stronger form of the lemma and I am not able to solve it the question without this.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Have you tried this with simple examples, say $n=3$?

Comment: What do you mean by $k_2 \mid \dots \mid k_n$?

Comment: @VishnuKadiri $a\mid b$ means "$a$ divides $b$," i.e. $b$ is an integer multiple of $a$, and $a\mid b\mid c\mid \cdots$ means "$a\mid b$ and $b\mid c$ and $c\mid \cdots$"

Comment: Do you allow $a_1=0$?

Comment: @mr_e_man $a_i$s are natural numbers

Comment: That doesn't help. Some people define $\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,3,\cdots\}$ and others define $\mathbb N=\{1,2,3,\cdots\}$.

Comment: Consider the natural numbers $a_1=0,\;a_2=2,\;a_3=5$. Their GCD is $d=1$. The equation $0k_1+2k_2+5k_2k_3=1$ implies $(2+5k_3)\mid1$ and thus $(2+5k_3)=\pm1$; that is, $2\equiv\pm1\bmod5$, a contradiction.

Comment: @mr_e_man Thanks for your example but my question is about positive integers.